# Deserialize JSON into List

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, serialization

I am having trouble deserializing a JSON object to a List. My JSON object is as below:

```
[{
    "returnValue": [{
        "facility": "DRIO",
        "recrd_desc": "DEFAULT",
        "update_time": {
            "$date": 1509128545000
        },
        "control_num": 1,
        "starttime": {
            "$date": 1506830400000
        },
        "endtime": {
            "$date": 4102462799000
        },
        "can_exchange_rate": 2000
    },
    {
        "facility": "DRIO",
        "recrd_desc": "TEMP",
        "update_time": {
            "$date": 1521229607000
        },
        "control_num": 37,
        "starttime": {
            "$date": 1513040240000
        },
        "endtime": {
            "$date": 1544576240000
        },
        "can_exchange_rate": 2112
    },
    {
        "facility": "DRIO",
        "recrd_desc": "TEMP 3",
        "update_time": {
            "$date": 1521229399000
        },
        "control_num": 38,
        "starttime": {
            "$date": 1544576580000
        },
        "endtime": {
            "$date": 1576112580000
        },
        "can_exchange_rate": 2000
    }],
    "ok": 1.0
}]
```

and my C# Class is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace CSCApi.Models
{
    public class FareSchedResponse
    {
        public List<FareSched> ReturnValue { get; set; }
        public float Ok { get; set; }
    }

    public class FareSched
    {
        public string facility { get; set; }
        public string recrd_desc { get; set; }
        public Update_Time update_time { get; set; }
        public int control_num { get; set; }
        public Starttime starttime { get; set; }
        public Endtime endtime { get; set; }
        public int can_exchange_rate { get; set; }
    }

    public class Update_Time
    {
        public long date { get; set; }
    }

    public class Starttime
    {
        public long date { get; set; }
    }

    public class Endtime
    {
        public long date { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The issue that is happening is that the value returned for Update_Time, StartTime and EndTime are 0 instead of the actual long values. I am not sure where the error is.

Any help is appreciated.
NH

Deserialization Code:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

[HttpGet]
[Route("api/FareSchedule/GetFareChart/{ActivePlazaID}/{ControlNumber}")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetFareChartAsync(string ActivePlazaID, int ControlNumber)
{
    try
    {
        var json = await _dbCalls.GetFareChart(ActivePlazaID, ControlNumber);
        var r = ParseResponse<FareSchedResponse>(json);
        return Ok(r.ReturnValue);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return BadRequest(e.Message);
    }
}

public static T ParseResponse<T>(string json)
{
    try
    {
        List<T> r = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(FormatAsList(json));
        if (r != null)
            return r[0];
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
    }
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(FormatAsList(json));
}

public static string FormatAsList(string json)
{
    try
    {
        var retVal = json;
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(retVal) && retVal.IndexOf(":[") <= 0)
        {
            retVal = retVal.Replace("[{\"returnValue\":", "[{\"returnValue\":[");
            retVal = retVal.Replace(",\"ok\":", "],\"ok\":");
            return retVal;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        // do nothing
    }
    return json;
}
```

Comment: Because your code is named "date" and the json is "$date", if you are using JSON.NET (like you should be) you can use the [JsonProperty](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonPropertyName.htm) attribute to give it a custom serialied/deserialized name

Comment: Consider using C# [Naming Guidelines -  PascalCasing is always used for property names.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/names-of-type-members).  If you're using Json.Net, it's not case sensitive by default.

Comment: Please, provide code for actual serialization process.

Comment: Please show your deserialization code

Comment: I don't have access to the actual serialization process. The code that outputs the JSON object is an Informix database's driver-free JSON Serializer that outputs stored procedures, tables output data as JSON. The stored procedure code outputs Informix datatype DateTime(Year to second) and the JSONSerializer(thich is Java code) is outputting the datetime value as "$date". I could modify the stored procedure to spit out a string(deal with conversion process on the web api side of it).

Comment: Deserialization code:

Comment: [HttpGet]
        [Route("api/FareSchedule/GetFareChart/{ActivePlazaID}/{ControlNumber}")]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetFareChartAsync(string ActivePlazaID, int ControlNumber)
        {
            try
            {
                var json = await _dbCalls.GetFareChart(ActivePlazaID, ControlNumber);
                var r = ParseResponse<FareSchedResponse>(json);
                return Ok(r.ReturnValue);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return BadRequest(e.Message);
            }
        }

Comment: @nhesuru10 that needs to be added to your question, not the comments

Comment: @nhesuru10 also see my earlier comment.  Its what you need to fix this problem

Comment: maccettura, I will try your solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @maccetura mentioned you just need to use an attribute in your models. This way you can also have a readable property names that follow C# naming conventions. If you use JSON.NET then you can choose between `JsonProperty` or `DataMember` attributes.

There are a lot of web sites that can help you to generate a C# models based on JSON. Just google something like *JSON to C#*.

The second generator I tried was smart enough to use `JsonProperty` attribute. So here are some examples of what I got:

```
public partial class Time
{
    [JsonProperty("$date")]
    public long Date { get; set; }
}

public partial class ReturnValue
{
    [JsonProperty("facility")]
    public string Facility { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("recrd_desc")]
    public string RecrdDesc { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("update_time")]
    public Time UpdateTime { get; set; }  

    //Other properties
}
```

I hope you can easily generate the remaining stuff.